# How do i find character position (row, col) in multi-line string?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

How i can find position of current character in multi-line string?
If every line in a string was the same length it would be easy. E.g.

```js
const str = `hello
hello
hello`

const findPos = (str, ind) => {
  const [cols] = str.split('\n');
  return { row: ind / cols.length | 0, col: ind % cols.length };
};

findPos(str, 12) // { row: 2, col: 2 }
```

But how can i do it, if every row is different length? E.g.

```js
const str = `hello
from
my
old
friend!`

findPos(str , 12) // { row: 3, col: 1 }
```

Comment: which character you want to find?

Comment: @brk every single char in a string, complete result would be array of location objects [{ row: number, col: number}, { row: number, col: number}, { row: number, col: number} ...etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop to iterate over the split lines, subtracting the length of the current line from the number of characters to go. If the length is shorter than the number of characters to go, return the characters to go as the `col`, and the number of lines iterated over as the `row`:

```js
const findPos = (input, indexToFind) => {
  const lines = input.split('\n');
  let charsToGo = indexToFind;
  let lineIndex = 0;
  while (lineIndex < lines.length) {
    const line = lines[lineIndex];
    const char = line[charsToGo];
    if (char) {
      return { row: lineIndex, col: charsToGo };
    }
    charsToGo -= line.length;
    lineIndex++;
  }
  return 'None';
};

const str = `hello
from
my
old
friend!`

console.log(findPos(str , 12)); // { row: 3, col: 1 }
```

Note that this does *not* consider the newlines as characters to be iterated over, which seems to be in line with your expected output. For an example of this generating a position for all characters in the string see the following snippet:

```js
const findPos = (input, indexToFind) => {
  const lines = input.split('\n');
  let charsToGo = indexToFind;
  let lineIndex = 0;
  while (lineIndex < lines.length) {
    const line = lines[lineIndex];
    const char = line[charsToGo];
    if (char) {
      return { row: lineIndex, col: charsToGo };
    }
    charsToGo -= line.length;
    lineIndex++;
  }
  return 'None';
};

const str = `hello
from
my
old
friend!`

const lenWithoutNewlines = str.length - str.match(/\n/g).length;
for (let i = 0; i < lenWithoutNewlines; i++) {
  console.log(findPos(str , i));
}
```

Comment: how can i improve this to take in account newline characters?

Answer (score 0):

when your requirement is to find out the array of the location of each character

You don't need to create a function to find location one by one.

Also when creating the objects you can keep the placeholder and character for quick search.

```js
const str = `hello
from
my
old
friend!`

function createPos(str) {
  let out = str.split('\n').map(e => [...e]);
  let place = 1;
  return out.map((arr, row) => arr.map((char, col) => ({ char, row, col, place: place++ }))).flat();
}

function findPos(str, n) {
  return createPos(str).find(e => e.place === n)
}

console.log('all chars\n', createPos(str));
console.log('found char\n',findPos(str, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
const findPosition = (input, indexToFind) => {
    const preChunk = input.substr(0, indexToFind);
    const row = preChunk.split('\n').length - 1;
    const lastIndexOfNewLine = input.lastIndexOf('\n', indexToFind);
    const col = lastIndexOfNewLine > 0 ? indexToFind - lastIndexOfNewLine - 1 : indexToFind;
    return {row, col};
};
```